# How do I refer to a specific app in urls.py? (Django)

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a simple blog with Django and I'm following [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/python-from-scratch-creating-a-dynamic-website/).

It says that I should refer to a specific app in urls.py by typing this:

```
url(r'^$', 'FirstBlog.blog.views.home', name='home')
```

Where FirstBlog is the project name and blog is the app name where the views file is located. For me this doesn't work, but if I remove the "Firstblog" part and just use blog.views.home, it works. That is, when I run the test server in my web browser I can see what's in my "index.html" file. Why is this? I'm new to this and would be grateful if anyone could explain how the urls.py works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an old tutorial. Best practice nowadays is to drop project name in case it changes. So if you put your app to another project it should work without any changes, that's why imports start with app name and not project name anymore.